# Create rounded corner and status bar padding overlay Android 10

Tags: android, overlay, statusbar

I am compiling pixel experience 10 but the status bar presents a huge padding and the device in stock rom uses software corner rounding. Can anyone give me a hand on building an overlay for these two values please?

Comment: please share code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For software rounded corners, create an overlay for `frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml` and inside:
Only `<dimen name="rounded_corner_radius">100px</dimen>` if top and bottom corners have the same radius, or both `<dimen name="rounded_corner_radius_top">110px</dimen>` and `<dimen name="rounded_corner_radius_bottom">130px</dimen>` if they are different.

For side padding concering rounded corners, create an overlay for `frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/values/dimens.xml` and inside `<dimen name="rounded_corner_content_padding">16dp</dimen>`

Comment: I actually cherry-picked the rounded corners overlay a while ago but I was still having that padding, I'll include it, thanks!